# Call WCF service from ASP.NET core 3.1 API

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am getting below error when I am trying to call WCF service from ASP.Net Core, this is happening only when both wcf service and API deployed on IIS 10.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted) System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: No connection
> could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
> ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: **No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. at
> **System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)**

I am able to connect same WCF service from ASP.NET MVC controller. It fails only when we access from .net core.

Any thoughts here, will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pani

Comment: This may happen because there is no service listening on the specified port, or the firewall may be blocking you.

Comment: Show us your code how do you call WCF from .net core.

Answer (score 1):

It was my bad, when we add an WCF service reference, to .net stranded library it will end up with adding "**ConnectedService.json**", this JSON will have reference to WCF endpoint, i was going by that. **But actually reference.cs was not reading a URL from ConnectedService.json, it was hard coded in reference.cs**.

**Solution is I had overwrite the URL while creating an instance of service client.**

SomeServiceClient = new MyWebService.SomeServiceClient();
IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
SomeServiceClient.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(configuration?.GetSection("WSSettings")?.GetSection("WSEndPoint")?.Value);

Where WSSettings is section in appsettings.json and WSEndPoint is key in that contain WCF endpoint